# Why NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs.NewItems Property is a list?

Tags: c#, wpf

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.notifycollectionchangedeventargs.newitems(v=vs.110).aspx

From the above link, it says this property

> Gets the list of new items involved in the change.

Since the collection only supports Add,Remove, Move for a single element, why this property returns a IList interface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A collection type that implements this interface could have a method that adds multiple items in a single call, similar to the [`List<T>.AddRange(IEnumerable<T>)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

The fact that `ObservableCollection` doesn't have such a method doesn't mean other collection types couldn't. However, `ObservableCollection` will always pass only 1 element (or `null`) to the `NewItems` collection of a NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs.